# Dense set in $T_2$-space.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Given a $T_2$-space $X$ and a dense set $M \subset X$ with cardinality $m$ we shall conclude from this that $\operatorname{card}(X) \le 2^{2^m}$. I don't get this: $M$ is always closed as it consists of isolated points ($T_1$-property), so $\overline{M} = M$. Therefore, M is only dense iff $X=M$ or where am I wrong? Either, this is a trick question or I totally miss the point of this excercise.

Comment: What do you think the T$_1$ property is? It's **not** "each point is isolated", it's "each point is closed". The real line has the T$_1$ property.

Comment: yes, but if each point is closed, then $M$ as their FINITE union is also closed, right?

Comment: I think this question only has non-trivial content if we understand $m$ to be an infinite cardinal.  If $m$ is finite your argument is correct.

Comment: @NateEldredge ah, okay. The problem is I don't know much about the concept of these numbers if they are not finite. But this would mean that I need to show that $|X| \le |P(P(M))|$. Do you have a hint for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: given $x \in X$, consider the question: for which subsets $A \subset M$ do we have $x \in \bar{A}$?  Show that the answer to this question completely determines $x$.

That is, show that the map
$$X \ni x \mapsto \{ A \subset M : x \in \bar{A} \} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(M))$$
is injective.

Comment: great, got it...thanks